# What is the correct set elements for these

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following specifications:

- $U = \{x: x$ is an integer, $0 < x < 10\}$
- $M = \{x: Y – 1, Y$ is prime number less than $10\}$
- $N = \{x: x^2< Z, Z$ is the smallest prime number$\}$

My attempt:

- $U = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$
- $M = \{1,2,4,6\}$
- $N = \{1\}$

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: For $N$, is $x$ restricted to natural numbers or integers?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Yes, this is correct.  Except (maybe) N.  If $x$ is an integer then N = {-1,0,1}.  If $x$ can be a real number then N is {x|$\sqrt{2} < x < \sqrt{2}$}.  If x can be complex... but if x is restricted to the natural numbers N = {1}.  But I think in context of the first set N is restricted to integers and N-{-1,0,1}

Answer (score 0):

The integers are $.... -2 < -1 < 0 < 1 < 2 ......$.  The integers between 0 and 10 (not inclusive) are {1,2,3,....,9} so

$U = {1,2,3....,8,9}

The prime numbers less that 10 are 2,3,5, and 7.  So $M = \{2-1,3-1,5-1,7-1\} = \{1,2,4,6\}$

The smallest prime is 2 so this is the set of all squares less than 2.  The squares are $0^2 = 0; \pm 1^2 = 1; \pm 2^2 = 4;... $ etc.  So $N = \{-1,0,1\}$